# How Do i turn off tracked changes using macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been trying to create a macro that will automatically run when I open a new word document that will verify that tracked changes are turned off. For some reason, whenever I run a macro that opens a new word document that is a .dotm file that contains a form, it turns on tracked changes and I have not told it to do so.

I have tried various different ways of fixing this issue.

Before I close the User form that has been opened when I opened the new file, I add this line

```
 ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
```

I also tried with an if statement

```
if(ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions) then
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
end if
```

I also tried doing it so that it was not even involved in the user form at all but the document itself by inserting it in the "ThisDocument" section under the "Microsoft Word Objects" File. Here is what is located there.

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    UserFormInfo.Show
    'ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("cursor").Select
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    ActiveDocument.Save
End Sub
```

I expect to have this turn off tracked changes, however, this does not occur. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in Private Sub Document_New(), does the code run? Also: if(ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions) then Debug.Print "I'm here"

Comment: Is this just with the one dotm file, or all dotm files? dotm means the file contains macros. Are any of these macros executing and possibly over-riding your code? Try putting the following line of code in the macro that creates a new document, just before `Documents.Add`: `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` This should prevent "auto" macros from executing.

Comment: The code does run @peakpeak. I am just not sure why it won't work properly. Looking into it more.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me is I had to remake my template. I had to export my user form so that it was fully removed from all my word files and then remake the template, after that, I had no problem with tracked changes turning on when I ran my macro to open this template. I believe it was a setting I must have had turned on when I had made my template.